# CSS Overstate for Responsive Layout

Tags: html, css, rollover

I'm using standard CSS (background positioning) to achieve a simple rollover state. The code has specified widths in pixels which presents an issue in the context of a fluid layout. Can someone recommend a way to achieve the same rollover effect with "fluidity" - meaning, the image can change sizes as needed based on browser size. Thanks in advance :)

Jfiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/QP96Q/

The CSS is below:

```
a.widgetbook {
    display:block;
    width: 369px;
    height: 85px;
    background: url("images/btn-books.jpg") no-repeat left;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}

a.widgetbook:hover {
    background-position: -369px 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="widgetbook">
</a>
<br>
<a href="#" class="widgetcontact">
```

Comment: please create a jsfiddle for better analysis/quick answer or provide any working sample

Comment: Take a look at example 5, you can customize it for more than one screen
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Per your suggestion, I created a JS fiddle to illustrate what I mean. Also, when I posted the original css, I had put in 100% as the width instead of 369px. At this point, I'd like to achieve this same effect, but have the button be resizeable.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style media="all">
.widgetbook {width: 25%;}
.widgetbook a {
    display:block;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 23%;
    background-image: url("btn-contact.jpg");
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.widgetbook a:hover {
    background-position: -100% 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="widgetbook">
    <a href="#" ></a>
</div>

<br>
<a href="#" class="widgetcontact">

</body>
</html>
```

Note: I had to remove the original URL because SO wouldn't let me post it, so just put it back in, or view this pen: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/DELai

Comment: I came up with a similar solution. The key here is the `background-size` property. In mine, I set the width and height to 100% but kept the max-width and max-height properties at the original values so you would get a nice scale down effect but not get a bad result when you scale up. http://jsfiddle.net/cw6hN/

Comment: Nice example. You should post it as an answer. :-)

Comment: Thank you both for your responses. Ralph, I agree that Rescue's solution is ideal since I wouldn't have to declare a percentage width :) This is exactly what I was looking for and I appreciate both of your efforts in providing an answer. While I have everything I need now, I would still like to understand the role of background-size: 200%. Thanks again!

Comment: RescueCreative, if you would post your comment as the answer, I'd gladly mark it as solved.